# Directive with async data from $resource no initializing properly

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple carousel. Source images are got through `$resource`. I need a kind of watch expression that notify that data has changed. I need to initialize the gallery with the first photo contained in the array located in ng-model attribute once I have this data.

The code:

```
app.directive('ngCarousel', function() {

    var template =  //...;

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {data:'='},
        compile:function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            tElement.html(template);

            //...

            return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

                //...

                attrs.$watch(scope.$modelValue, function() {
                    //initialize the template
                })
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need a kind of watch expression that notify that data has changed.

Add a callback to your $resource query.  I.e., instead of (I'm guessing here, since you didn't provide any code showing how you are using $resource)

```
$scope.image1 = MyResourceWrapper.query()
```

do this instead:

```
MyResourceWrapper.query( function(data) {
   // Now you know the data has arrived.  Initialize your gallery, etc.
   ...
}
```

---

See also http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/#/carousel